# Create "Bingo Card" in Report Builder

Tags: reporting-services, ssms, reportbuilder

I have an SSMS query that list orders numbers.  In Report Builder we want these order numbers to expand right in the columns and down in the rows to resemble a bingo board.  When an order has been shipped that order (cell) would turn green.  How can I fill up the report page with one cell across the columns and down  the rows?

I have not been able to figure this one out.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming here that you have a simple list of order numbers and some kind of status to indicate complete/shipped.

I've created a simple table variable to use as the sample data with the following...

```
DECLARE @Orders TABLE(OrderID int IDENTITY(1000,1), OrderStatus INT)
INSERT INTO @Orders(OrderStatus) VALUES (1), (0), (0), (1), (1), (1), (0), (1), (0), (0), (0), (0), (1), (1), (1), (0), (0), (1), (1), (0), (0), (1)

SELECT * FROM @Orders
```

This gives us the following (truncated)
[image]

From here you can use your own order table.

Next we need to calculate the row and column numbers. To do this I've set a variable to give the number of required columns, you can set this as you please or even pass it in from, the report as a report parameter, for now it'll be static.

So the full query looks like this

```
DECLARE @Orders TABLE(OrderID int IDENTITY(1000,1), OrderStatus INT)
INSERT INTO @Orders(OrderStatus) VALUES (1), (0), (0), (1), (1), (1), (0), (1), (0), (0), (0), (0), (1), (1), (1), (0), (0), (1), (1), (0), (0), (1)

DECLARE @MaxCols int = 5

SELECT 
    OrderID,
    OrderStatus,
    ColNum = (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY OrderID)-1)%@MaxCols, 
    RowNum = (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY OrderID)-1)/@MaxCols
    FROM @Orders
```

This gives us this (truncated)
[image]

Now in our report, all we need to do is add a dataset with the above as the dataset query, then add a matrix control.

Drag the ColNum to the column placeholder, RowNum to the row placeholder, OrderID to the data placeholder.

Next we can set the background to green if the OrderStatus = 1 .

Finally we can delete the header rows and column if required.

Here's a 1 minute GIF showing the process of building the report. (right-click and open in new window to make it bigger if needed)

[image]